# create hive table from tab separated file in s3 using interactive mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I've loaded tab separated files into S3 that with this type of folders under the bucket:
bucket --> se --> y=2013 --> m=07 --> d=14 --> h=00

each subfolder has 1 file that represent on hour of my traffic.

I then created an EMR workflow to run in interactive mode with hive.

When I log in to the master and get into hive I run this command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE se (
id bigint,
oc_date timestamp)
partitioned by (y string, m string, d string, h string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://bi_data';
```

I get this error message:

> FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The
>   bucket name parameter must be specified when listing objects in a bucket
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Can anybody help?

***UPDATE***
Even if I try to use string fields only, I get the same error.
Create table with strings:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE se (
id string,
oc_date string)
partitioned by (y string, m string, d string, h string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://bi_data';
```

**Hive version 0.8.1.8**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, the solution is that I had two mistakes:

1. When writing only the bucket name you should have a trailing slash in the S3 path.
   reference [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html)
2. The underscore is also an issue, the bucket name should be DNS compliant.

Hope I helped someone with this.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The underscore cost me a couple of hours.